# Delphi Equivalent To Visual Studio Coded UI Test?

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, testing, user-interface

As the title implies I am trying to figure out if there is a Delphi equivalent (whether built in or 3rd party component) of the coded UI test feature in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing built in to the best of my knowledge. Take a look at third party product called TestComplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Delphi include **DUnit**. DUnit includes special helper classes for automated UI testing. I [read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx) that VS automatically creates the test code, this feature is not available in DUnit.

The code is in DUnit\src\GUITesting.pas and contains checks like

```
procedure CheckFocused(Control :TControl; Addrs :Pointer = nil); overload;
procedure CheckFocused(ControlName :string);                    overload;

procedure CheckEnabled(Control :TControl; Addrs :Pointer = nil);  overload;
procedure CheckEnabled(ControlName :string);                     overload;

procedure CheckVisible(Control :TControl; Addrs :Pointer = nil);  overload;
procedure CheckVisible(ControlName :string);                     overload;
procedure CheckVisible;
```

---

Also related to Delphi UI testing is the Open Component Test Framework (**OpenCTF**) I wrote a while ago. This framework can be used to check all Forms and Frames in a Delphi application.

It is a rule-based test case generator for DUnit, and creates the tests at run time (it is not a source code generator). This has the advantage that test rules can be defined one time and then applied to all components of the project with one line of code.

It is open source, available at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/openctf/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually needed the feature to test a Web App built with Coldfusion so I am not sure if either of those options will suffice right now.

I have found a few other options but neither of them generate the test code in Object pascal which is kind of sad. Looks like I am going t have to settle on using code generated in C# or Javascript for now.

Comment: @Gary for Web App tests, Canoo WebTest, Selenium and JMeter might be helpful

Comment: Just my 2ct working with GUITesting. I didn't manage to get it working in all cases where I was actually testing the behaviour of a form by using the "ClickOn..." methods. Clicking a radiobutton or checkbox worked sometimes, but not all the time. Doing it manually on the form worked as expected, but doing it from code using GUITesting, the click was executed, but the other controls were not updated wrt visibility/enabledness. Adding sleeps and waiting for message loop to catch up, etc, all didn't help. In the end I gave up (time constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. @mjn, I will look into those options. Right now I think I am going to try using either watin test recorder and see how it goes.

Comment: When I last looked at DUnit's GUI testing offering it seemed to be incredibly sparse and basically looked like a rather useless afterthought. Am I wrong?